# React-Native nesting maps without knowing key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native

I am making an app in react-native and I am gathering my data via API. I am trying to add a new feature where information is organized by date. So the API sends data that looks like this:

```
{
  "channel_count": "1",
  "channels": [
    {
      "logo": "default.png",
      "name": "Default Channel",
      "token": "default"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "2022-07-04": [
        {
          "body": "Body",
          "title": "Title"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "2022-07-01": [
        {
          "body": "Body",
          "title": "Title"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to 'get into' the messages in the JSON, but since I do not know which date, I can not go another layer deeper.

I want to display this data while organizing the messages by date. The issue is, how am I able to map the messages when I do not readily know what dates will be shown? This displays messages from a 7 day radius, but messages are not sent everyday, as shown in the JSON.

On a basic level, I want my app to look like this:

Date: 2022-07-04

Title: Title

Body: Body

---

Date: 2022-07-01

Title: Title

Body: Body

(and when the app is more complete with more data, the messages will still be organized by date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your need, you can try below code it should work for you.

```
 const data = {
  "channel_count": "1",
  "channels": [
    {
      "logo": "default.png",
      "name": "Default Channel",
      "token": "default"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "2022-07-04": [
        {
          "body": "Body",
          "title": "Title"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "2022-07-01": [
        {
          "body": "Body",
          "title": "Title"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const { messages } = data || {};

const mappedData = (messages || []).map(item => {
  const [key] = Object.keys(item);
  const [value] = item[key];
  return { date: key, body: value.body, title: value.title};
});

console.log("updatedData", mappedData)
```

Now you have your data in array of object in the for of

```
[{ date: "2022-07-04", body: "Body", title: "Title" }, ....]
```

you can use map and render data on your UI.

Comment: if you add another entry to a date, still only one message is logged

Comment: if you have multiple entry into date so you can try this, it should work for you

`const mappedData = [];
(messages || []).forEach(item => {
  const [key] = Object.keys(item);
  const values = item[key];
   values.forEach(value => (mappedData.push({ date: key, body: value.body, title: value.title})))
});

console.log("updatedData", mappedData)`

Answer (score 1):

Did you heard about `Object.entries`, `Object.values`, `Object.keys` and `for in` and `for of` loops?

```js
const data = {
  "channel_count": "1",
  "channels": [
    {
      "logo": "default.png",
      "name": "Default Channel",
      "token": "default"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "2022-07-04": [
        {
          "body": "Body",
          "title": "Title"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "2022-07-01": [
        {
          "body": "Body",
          "title": "Title"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

console.log(data.messages.flatMap(e => Object.entries(e)))
```